# Execute a script on package manager console via Tools > External tools

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework-core

I would like to be able to run Entity Framework Cores dbScaffold by using a shortcut. so far this works well if I use entity framework core's CLI tools and link that script as external tool ([as described here](https://nickmeldrum.com/blog/how-to-run-powershell-scripts-from-solution-explorer-in-visual-studio-2010)).

but this requires the EF tools to be installed. If I execute that script in package manager console just having the EF Core Design nuget package referenced is enough.

So my question is: Is there any way to execute a .ps1 script from Tools > External tools inside Visual studio 2019 on the package manager console?